# Axios bad request status 400

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm having this issue `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400`

I checked the console and I test manually the url and It worked, so I don't know what's wrong, this code:

```
//file controller.js

//Set Create Session
exports.setSession = async (req, res) => {
    const data = await request({
        path: process.env.APP_LOCALHOST_URL + urlLogin.setCreateSession,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
    });
    
    return res.json(data);
}


//file request.js
exports.request = async ({path, method = "GET", body }) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios({
            method: method,
            url: path,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: body
          }); 
          return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
    }
}
```

the function `setSession` is to call in my routes file, and the function request is my reusable component. My intention is to use the function request in many functions, these could be of the `GET, DELETE, PUT, POST, PATCH` type.

So, currently I get this on console:

```
data: {
  error: '5',
  errorId: 'badRequest',
  errorString: 'Internal error: Undefined JSON value.'
}
```

Comment: Please can you try with outh JSON.stringfy(). In my opinion it doesn't need

Comment: yes I tried it, but a get the same issue